# Optimum buffer to memory ratio

Tags: memory, memory-management, buffer, data-transfer, data-acquisition

I am trying to build a DAQ using Sparrow's Kmax. I have a ready template in which the total memory is `16 MB`.

```
static final int evSize = 4; // The num of parameters per event of this type                        

static final int BUF_SIZE = evSize*1000;   /** <------------------Why pick this buffer size*/ // Buffer size

static final int LP_MEM_TOP = 0xFFFF00;  // Memory size 16MB

static final int READ_START = LP_MEM_TOP  -  BUF_SIZE; // We start the read/write pointer 1 buffer before the end
```

In the above code you can see that the buffer is very small compared to the total memory. From what  know, the buffer is the temporary memory where data is stored before being sent to the computer.

In my case I am using a `SCSI` bus to transfer the data and the system is really slow. What can I do with the buffer to increase the speed or the performance? Is there a particular reason to have such a small buffer? I am not sure if I have understood what exactly does the memory and the buffer do.

Any help is more than welcome!!!